# When can interpretations be "optimized"?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

*To make this more readable, I've put some definitions/conventions at the end of this question.*

I'm interested in when a given interpretation isn't "missing any information." Specifically, say that an interpretation $\Phi$ in a theory $T$ is **optimal** iff for every extension $\Psi$, every $\Sigma_\Phi$-structure $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying everything $T$ proves about $\Phi$ can be expanded to a $\Sigma_\Psi$-structure $\mathcal{A}'$ satisfying everything $T$ proves about $\Psi$. And say that an interpretation is **weakly optimal** if the above holds restricted to countable structures. *(Relating this to an earlier question of mine, an optimal interpretation is "relatively [sharp](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433486/can-we-always-sharpen-interpretations)," except now I'm explicitly disallowing "infinitely long" interpretations - see the end of this question.)*

- Example: the usual interpretation of $\mathsf{ACF_0}$ inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$.
- Weak example(?): I believe that the usual interpretation of $\mathsf{PA}$ inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is weakly optimal, due to the role of recursive saturation. It's not clear to me whether it is optimal, however.
- Non-example: the obvious interpretation of "the naturals with only the same-parity relation" in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is not optimal (consider a pair of infinite sets with different cardinalities). However, this interpretation does have an optimal extension, e.g. by adding the successor function.

On a very general level, I'd like to know which theories $T$ have the property that every interpretation in $T$ can be extended to an optimal (or weakly optimal) interpretation - call this "**(weak) optimizability**" of $T$. I suspect that's too broad to actually be answered, so here's a more tractable version of that question:

> **Question 1**: Is every first-order theory interpretable in a (weakly) optimizable theory?

More locally, I'm curious whether the usual interpretation of arithmetic in set theory is optimal (and not just weakly optimal):

> **Question 2**: Is the usual interpretation of arithmetic in set theory optimal?

---

### Basic conventions/definitions

All languages are finite, and all theories are first-order. An **interpretation** in a first-order theory $T$ will be a tuple $(\delta,\eta,F)$ where (for some $n$) $\delta$ is an $n$-ary formula, $\eta$ is a $2n$-ary formula which $T$ proves defines an equivalence relation on $\delta$, and $F$ is a **finite** set of formulas such that each $\varphi\in F$ has arity $kn$ for some $k$ and is $T$-provably well-defined on $\delta/\eta$. An interpretation $\Phi$ **extends** an interpretation $\Psi$ iff the $\delta$- and $\eta$-parts of $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are the same and the $F$-part of $\Phi$ contains the $F$-part of $\Psi$. Given an interpretation $\Phi$, let $\Sigma_\Phi$ be the language consisting of a relation symbol for each formula in the $F$-part of $\Phi$ (so $\Phi$ interprets a $\Sigma_\Phi$-theory in $T$).

This is all a bit brief, but it's hopefully clear what's meant. I'm happy to expand on any of it!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to Question 2 is negative and the answer to Question 1 is positive.

In fact the usual interpretation $\Phi$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is not even weakly optimal. Indeed, consider the extension $\Psi$ of $\Phi$ by a
predicate on naturals that is a truth definition for $\mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{PA}}$. For any countable non-standard model $M\models \Psi[\mathsf{ZFC}]$ its $\mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{PA}}$-fragment will be recursively saturated. However, $\Phi[\mathsf{ZFC}]$ as any extension of $\mathsf{PA}$ in the language of $\mathsf{PA}$ has countable non-standard models that are not recursively saturated (e.g. fixing a non-standard model $N\models \Phi[\mathsf{ZFC}]$ and a non-standard number $c\in M$, the submodel
of $N$ on definable elements with parameter $c$ will be a countable model of $\Phi[\mathsf{ZFC}]$ that is not recursively saturated).

Notice that any theory (with finite signature) could be interpreted in $\mathsf{Th}(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\times,P)$, for some predicate $P$. Let me now prove that any $T$ of the form $\mathsf{Th}(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\times,P)$ is optimizable. Notice that any interpretation in $T$ is either definably isomorphic to an interpretation on the whole domain or to an interpretation with the domain $[0,S^n(0))$, for some natural $n$. Interpretations of the first kind are optimal since their definably isomorphic copies could be extended by $0,S,+,\times$, and $P$. Interpretations of the second kind are optimal since they correspond to fixed finite models.